# Laravel: npm run watch Error

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm

I was working on a project and I run 'npm run watch'
and I got this error. I was working normally but all of sudden I got this error!

```
> @ watch C:\projects\tests\blog
> node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development                                          
node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --     
config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

undefined:1



SyntaxError: Unexpected token

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe"        
"C:\\Users\\Bruno\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "watch"
npm ERR! node v6.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.3.0
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ watch: `node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js        
NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ watch script 'node node_modules/cross-  env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the  package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js        
NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Bruno\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-03-20T13_06_27_111Z-debug.log
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 5):

> If you are developing on a Windows system or you are running your VM on a Windows host system, you may need to run the npm install command with the --no-bin-links switch enabled:

Install using this command:

```
npm install --no-bin-links
```

And run this after:

```
npm run watch-poll
```

[Source for 5.4](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mix#running-mix)

[Source for <= 5.3](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/elixir#running-elixir)

Answer (score 0):

I just simply deleted built CSS and JS files as well as the `mix-manifest.json` file. Things worked afterwards

Answer (score 0):

For me just deleted the `mix-manifest.json` file. Then did `npm run watch-poll`

My `package.json` script.

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch-poll": "node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --watch-poll --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "hot": "node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "production": "node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
  },
```

Running laravel from xampp shell (windows 7)

Answer (score 0):

Note: Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.

- Clear NPM's cache:
  `sudo npm cache clean -f`
- Install [called 'n'](https://github.com/tj/n):
  `sudo npm install -g n`
- Install latest stable Node.js version: `sudo n stable`

Alternatively pick a specific version and install like this:

`sudo n (wanted node version)`

You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with: `npm bugs`

It's literally described in the log output what to do...

Answer (score 0):

try this also:
npm uninstall --save-dev sass-loader

It just ran perfectly when i tried to run the command npm run dev / npm run watch